# Connect close/overlapping detected bounding boxes

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, computer-vision

I'm working with text detection in Tensorflow, using [EAST: An Efficient and Accurate Scene Text Detector](https://github.com/argman/EAST).

And I'm struggling to find any decent/library that helps grouping close and overlapping bounding boxes like in the example:

[image]

I think it's a simple problem, there must be some OpenCV/Tensorflow function for this that I don't know yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post your code, how you detect these boxes; plus the original image.

Comment: Non-maximum suppression is a technique for combining overlapping bounding boxes. Sample code for this is available on PyImageSearch blog. but for connecting nearby boxes, I think you might have to write your own code.